# SignalR + Node WebKit/Node fails to connect over websockets when authenticated

Tags: asp.net, node.js, signalr, node-webkit

This is a node webkit application that manages a bunch of webkit windows. Each webkit window uses signalR to connect to a MVC/webApi/signalR stack with no problems. Each window connects to 1-3 hubs over websockets. Everything works well.

My client wants to use SignalR inside the base node application that manages all the other windows. This is where things are getting 'interesting'...

So although the node app is running in a webkit environment it is served from the file system (header:origin=file://)

So i have started up signalR like (no JSONP as i'm targeting websockets)

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
           {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();

                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

So when i connect in the node app before the user logs into one of the windows spawned from Node, signalR connects over websockets fine, and i don't get any errors when they login(i.e. user has changed identity).

```
  var connection = window.$.hubConnection("http://localhost");
  connection.logging = true;
  connection.start()
        .done(function () { console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Could not connect'); });
```

the issue is i don't have the identity in the HubCallerConext serverside.

So if the user logs in first, then the node application has the cookies created in the other spawned window and this is where things get weird. SignalR fails to connect over websockets with the following error (from fiddler)

*Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.*

Here is the negotiate call and then the failing call to connect (upgrade) over websockets.
**I have a fiddler rule replacing Origin:file:// with localhost.** just in case this was effecting it.

```
GET http://localhost/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=qs09pHGxr6x5fff1GJ%2FChWUnpSLX5ljV8FuS3h06P%2FhpS55cjNvh2uFHHTXukDI%2BK%2BcgsC6%2BWVJHba4xrkt6IVc2KwGIfm4eeyHrigNFRotjBYKb&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22windowmanagementhub%22%7D%5D&_=1429572950768 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
 X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 2E81759B-036D-4E92-ADF4-865AFBF59D2
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-GB,en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
 Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=opyggkqxnudnuag5mtxy40ai; __APPLICATION_LANGUAGE=en-GB; __RequestVerificationToken=eoB...GHjTo1; .ASPXAUTH=6909...82ED0; WindowsAuthCookie.LoginName=userName
 Origin: http://localhost
```

and response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 23:46:49 GMT

177
{"Url":"/signalr","ConnectionToken":"LwJz6Ev3+9C/NbKBqHkrI8KwYaz53qiBbzDJVlcse1qRXU3loCqOI68kUb4kpyk8gdQlkKRJ0wBrpb+VVtUMFtrtSQOEhGQE9ZNaMDBajyK2/Evz","ConnectionId":"68e7751b-aaee-4ed7-aa36-a2d1ab25107f","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"ProtocolVersion":"1.4","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}
0
```

then the following connect headers, **which is the request that gets the 403**

```
GET http://localhost/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=LwJz6Ev3%2B9C%2FNbKBqHkrI8KwYaz53qiBbzDJVlcse1qRXU3loCqOI68kUb4kpyk8gdQlkKRJ0wBrpb%2BVVtUMFtrtSQOEhGQE9ZNaMDBajyK2%2FEvz&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22windowmanagementhub%22%7D%5D&tid=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent:
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-us;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Sec-WebSocket-Key: HqfgeBw4svkTTpBK2CfaJA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

and the 403 response

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 23:46:49 GMT

61
Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.
0
```

Here is the javascript error in the console (from jquery.signalR 2.1.2, different connection ids, tokens)

```
WebSocket connection to 
'ws://localhost/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=xzGshRPvF1XvGnq2S2nDmGZ3TISMGEt01Au0z9J%2FAfMa2OtQUMW5XX5HgW0I4n2MK5UfGfpJ4%2Fl7OkiRpQlSIFrDkfy25WHScwpkubBsn5403%2Ba3&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22windowmanagementhub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22browserloghub%22%7D%5D&tid=1' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

SignalR will then (correctly) fall back to SSE and connect successfully. I can see the Identity of the user serverside.

I would really like to understand why i can't connect over websockets when the user is authenticated. If i delay ALL windows from connecting to the server via signalR until the user is authenticated then i also see the same behavior.

any help or clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: anyone reading this bug, it's because Node-Webkit (Chrome/41.0.2272.76) is not sending the cookies on the upgrade request. When i run the code in desktop chrome (Chrome/42.0.2311.90) the cookies are sent as expected. I have tested the package in nwk 11.6 (fail), 11.13-pre (works), 12.0 (fail), 12.1 (fail). no idea why the cookies are not sent on that http upgrade request. Similar issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123862

Comment: Thank you for adding this! I've been fighting for a while to figure out why my websocket connections were missing cookies and thus falling back to long polling.

Comment: I have also logged an issue with NWK on Github. https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3422#issuecomment-101838959